# monitoring Tomcat using Tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat, monitoring

I'm using Tomcat jmxproxy and status to monitor a web application but there is to much useless  information in jmxproxy page and information like number of active connections aren't in any of them.Does anyone know how to filter the jmxproxy page and where I can find such information?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Using_the_JMX_Proxy_Servlet) is fairly clear about how to filter using jmxproxy.

Number of active connections (whether you are talking about JDBC DataSource or HTTP/AJP connections) is available through JMX, so you just aren't looking hard enough through the "useless" information provided by jmxproxy.

Try reading the [Tomcat Monitoring FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring) for information on some useful JMX beans you might want to monitor.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was very helpful.I looked again in jmxproxy but I can't find anything that show the number of active connections to tomcat. Do you know how can I find it?

Comment: Which connections are you looking for? JDBC DataSource connections or HTTP/AJP connections?

Comment: Look at the "thread usage" section of the Tomcat Monitoring FAQ (link already provided in my answer).